# holedata is not defined while loading ejs file after res.render

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am inserting the data into mongodb and then page rendering to success.ejs. In the success.ejs file I gave one link. When click link in the same success.js file data should fetch from mongodb and show in same success.ejs file. But before loading the success.ejs file after post the data in the console showing holedata is not defined error message.

My post data part in index.js file

```js
app.post('/signingin', function(req, res) {
      var item = {
        name: req.body.name,
        title: req.body.title,
        age: req.body.age
      };
      mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection('satyamsoft').insertOne(item, function(err, result){
          assert.equal(null, err);
          console.log('item inserted');
          db.close();
        });
      });
        res.render('pages/success');
        //console.log(req.body);
    });
```

My success.ejs page

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <% include ../partials/head %>
    <title>Post Jobs | Spyeer</title>
    <body>

        <% include ../partials/nav %>       
        <section class="get">
          <h2>Data Inserted</h2>
          <a href="/getdata">Get Data</a>
          <div>
            <ul>
                <% holedata.forEach(function(data) { %>
                    <li><%= data.this.name %> - <%= data.this.title %> - <%= data.this.age %></li>
                <% }); %>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>

        <% include ../partials/footer %>

        <% include ../partials/scripts %>

    </body>
</html>
```

get part code in index.js file

```js
app.get('/getdata', function(req, res){
      var resultArray = [];
      mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var cursor = db.collection('satyamsoft').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc, err){
          assert.equal(null, err);
          resultArray.push(doc);
          //console.log(resultArray);
        //res.render('pages/getdata', {holedata: resultArray});
      }, function(){
        db.close();
        res.render('pages/success', {holedata: resultArray});
      });
```

Please help me advance thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much.@ShubhamBatra

Comment: Also can you help me how to do single page app using embaded js. I mean when click buttons data should load in the same place.  Please help me. @ShubhamBatra

Comment: You have to share your code only then somebody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check every time page render there should be **holedata** either empty or with data like instead of `res.render('pages/success');` you should write `res.render('pages/success', {holedata: [] });`